ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined в HTML
в редакторе кода Pulsar(вроде аналог Atom) есть расширение emmet, оно должно позволять в HTML писать сразу тег с классом быстро то есть p.net преобразует в <p class="net"></p> но когда я так делаю выскакивает ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. я не понимаю что не так.

Не так то, что вы пытаетесь использовать расширение, которое давным-давно не поддерживается и никогда не предназначалось для Pulsar https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom/issues/676
